# Is there a twitter library for metro apps?

Tags: twitter, microsoft-metro

Do you know a twitter library for Windows 8 metro apps?

Comment: How in the world is this "not a real question"?  lmao

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen one up yet, BUT there is a sample in the [Windows 8 Samples Projects](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) that shows you how to get connected to twitter (and I think does a small task with the Auth Code using the Twitter REST API).

Generally speaking the oAuth (authentication) part is usually the hardest (this is true of Facebook, DropBox, and probably many others). Anyway the folder you want to check out is the "Web authentication broker sample" folder. That contains an example of connecting to Facebook, Twitter, and a few others.